# Non-isomorphic Heisenberg groups over rings

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups, heisenberg-groups

Suppose $R_1,R_2$ are finite unital commutative rings. Consider Heisenberg groups $H_3(R_1)$ and $H_3(R_2)$ (upper unitriangular marticies $3 \times 3$).

> **Proposition.** If $R_1 \not\cong R_2$ (as rings) then $H_3(R_1) \not\cong H_3(R_2)$ (as multiplicative groups).

Is that true? It seem that if $R_1$ and $R_2$ have not isomorphic additive groups then $H_3(R_1) \not\cong H_3(R_2)$, since they have not isomorphic centers. But what about general case, or is that too broad?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Theorem 1.13 of [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007294900221) *(The model theory of unitriangular groups, Ann. Pure Appl. Logic
68(3), 1994, 225-261)* by O. Belegradek says that the answer is positive even for infinite commutative rings.

However, Proposition 1.9 in the same paper asserts that this does not extend to the non-commutative (associative unital case). The counterexamples have the form $R_1=K\times K$, $R_2=K\times K^{\mathrm{op}}$, where $K$ is indecomposable and not isomorphic to $K^{\mathrm{op}}$.

Comment: Actually before I fixed the tags, the only "ring" tag was "commutative rings", so the question was quite clearly for commutative rings (which should have been more explicit). I added the tag "ra-..." because Lie algebras are lurking behind...

Comment: @YCor,  I never read tags. Anyway I give the answer in that case too.

Comment: Yes I know: this was no criticism but rather an excuse, since editing the tags, I sort of hid the only hint that the question was only in the commutative case. But of course it's great your answer both: just I would rather formulate it now saying that the answer is positive but not its extension to the non-commutative case.

Comment: Probably not worth editing. Also finite is not important.

Comment: I did it anyway :) btw you probably have in mind some finite ring not anti-isomorphic to itself?

Comment: Take an acyclic connected quiver that is not isomorphic to the quiver obtained by reversing its arrows and then take the path algebra over a finite field. Such guys are indecomposable and not self dual and finite.

Comment: I added that the answer is positive even for infinite commutative rings.

Comment: Not any such quiver works, if I'm correct (e.g. the connected quiver with 3 vertices, 2 edges with the same head doesn't). However some quiver with 4 vertices and 3 arrows works, with the path algebra $A$ with basis $(1,a,b,z,az,bz)$ and the obvious products ($1$ unit, all products 0 except those involving 1 and $a.z=az,b.z=az$). Then the left nil-center (not sure of terminology) $\{x:\forall y:xy=0\}$ is 3-dimensional for $A$ (basis $(az,bz,z)$) and 4-dimensional for $A^{\mathrm{op}}$ (basis $(az,bz,a,b)$), so $A$ and $A^{\mathrm{op}}$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: @YCor, Any such quiver works. By Gabriel's theorem two isomorphic basic finite dimensional algebras have isomorphic quivers. If you take two edges with the same head but different tails  over any field it has two simple projective left modules but only one simple projective right module so it is not isomorphic to its opposite

Comment: Simple projective left modules correspond to sources and simple projective right modules to sinks since empty paths give a complete set of primitive idempotents and no two give isomorphic simples.

Comment: I'm confused then about the definition. For this "$\to\leftarrow$" quiver, isn't the path algebra given by the basis $(1,a,b)$ with $ab=ba=0$ (thus commutative)? because there is no pair of composable edges...

Comment: The path algebra has basis all directed paths in the quiver including empty paths at each vertex. So it is 5 dimensional.

Comment: OK thanks. So this one $\to\leftarrow$ yields basis $(u,v,w,a,b)$ with nonzero products $u^2=u$, $v^2=v$, $w^2=w$, $ua=a=av$, $wb=b=bv$ (the unit is $u+v+w$). That it's not isomorphic to its opposite (over a field) can also be seen naively: while right multiplication by $a+b$ has rank 2 as linear operator, the left multiplication on the whole algebra by any element of the Jacobson radical (with basis $(a,b)$) has rank $\le 1$.

Comment: Great. We agree.

Comment: Thanks, @BenjaminSteinberg I did not know about that paper. I posted the question and then went offline... so I missed the interesting discussion.

Comment: @YCor thank you for valuable comments.